# how to redirect my user and send data between components?

Tags: reactjs

I want to push the user after the user clicks on button and send data to the destination page 
 in the `app.js` I have the routing 
and I have two other  components `/projects`  and `menu` 
in `/projects`  I want to push the user to `/menu`   after the user clicks on a button X and send the id of this button from `/projects` to `/menu`

project.js

```
 handleClick = index => {
          const selectedItem = this.state.data[index];

          console.log(selectedItem.id)
          }
```

app.js

```
 <Route exact path="/" component={First} />
          <ProtectedRoute logged_in={this.state.logged_in}  path="/Projects" render={()=><Projects username={this.state.username}/>} />
          <ProtectedRoute logged_in={this.state.logged_in}  path="/menu" render={()=><MenuH username={this.state.username}/>} />
          <ProtectedRoute logged_in={this.state.logged_in}  path ="/createProject" render={()=><CreateP username={this.state.username} id={this.state.id}/>}  />
          <ProtectedRoute logged_in={this.state.logged_in}  path ="/connect" render={()=><Newacount username={this.state.username} id={this.state.id}/>} />
          <ProtectedRoute logged_in={this.state.logged_in}  path ="/profile" render={()=><Profile user={this.state.user}/>} />
```

Comment: Are you trying to pass data between Routes ?? If that's the case you can pass the Id through URL. If that's the case see https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/url-params .

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect and send data with history prop

```
this.props.history.push({path: '/menu', state: {id: selectedItem.id}});
```

and then access data in menu component by `this.props.location.state.id`

Comment: after using your method this is the result : TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined

Comment: your menu component does not recieve location prop from router. To fix you can try:
`render={(props)=><MenuH {...props} username={this.state.username}/>}`
or
`render={<MenuH username={this.state.username}/>}`